# Eclipse 3.8 to 4.6 Migration Platform.getPlugin() returns null

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-neon

I have to migrate from Eclipse 3.8 to 4.6.
My problem is that in 4.6 (or earlier) Platform.getPlugin() got deprecated and will always return null.
Using the Bundles in place of plugins doesn't help me beacuse in that case we will have to break our public API.
Do you know if there is a way from the bundle to get the plugin ?

```
/**
 * As the org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility plug-in has been removed in
 * Eclipse 4.6 this method is not supported anymore.
 *
 */
@Deprecated
public static Plugin getPlugin(String id) {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Well `Plugin` extends `BundleActivator`. The `BundleContext` for a bundle does contain a reference to the BundleActivator but there doesn't seem to be any interface to access it.

Answer (score 0):

The question I have to ask is *what were you using it for*, and then point out that while `Platform#getPlugin(String)` is deprecated, `Plugin` itself is **not**. If your **Bundle-Activator** class extends `Plugin`, just have it save a reference to itself in its constructor, ala http://git.eclipse.org/c/sourceediting/webtools.sourceediting.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core/src/org/eclipse/jst/jsp/core/internal/JSPCorePlugin.java#n54 . Then it's just a matter of accessing it when you need it.