# Equivalent to the deprecated Platform.getPlugin(), need access to org.eclipse.ui plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, deprecated

In a custom plug-in that I need to migrate from Eclipse 4.5.2 to Eclipse 4.6.3, 
I'm using the following code to access the org.eclipse.ui plugin

```java
public class myClass extends Wizard {

...

   AbstractUIPlugin plugin = (AbstractUIPlugin) Platform.getPlugin("org.eclipse.ui");
   IDialogSettings settings = plugin.getDialogSettings();
   IDialogSettings section = workbenchSettings.getSection("myWizard");
   if (section == null) {
      section = workbenchSettings.addNewSection("myWizard");
   }
   setDialogSettings(section);

...

}
```

But since 4.6.0 the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility` plug-in has been removed. So I can't use the `Platform.getPlugin()` method.

I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41747468/eclipse-3-8-to-4-6-migration-platform-getplugin-returns-null) someone having an equivalent problem but with no answer.
And I've found [there](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/13735/) that I can access the plugin only if the creator expose the singleton.

So I have two questions:

1. Is the singleton of the `org.eclipse.ui` plug-in exposed ?
2. If yes, what is the equivalent of `Platform.getPlugin()` to access the `org.eclipse.ui` plug-in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no equivalent API to `Platform.getPlugin`. You can get limited information about other plugins using `Platform.getBundle` and `FileLocator.find` but that doesn't help here.

The `org.eclipse.ui` plugin does have a `UIPlugin.getDefault()` method but this is in an **internal** package so you would be breaking the [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html) if you used it.

For dialog settings it is standard practice to call the `getDialogSettings` on your own plugin not some other plugin which you don't control.

Comment: It's a code I didn't make so I don't always understand why it does things. Here I don't know why use org.eclipse.ui plugin. I tried without it, and use my plugin settings as you said, and it works. Thank you